# Div multiple borders for paper simulation

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a div with decoration borders. This div should be:

- responsive
- react to an resize operation
- and adjust it's height and width depending on the embeded image

What I have figured out yet is this fiddle example and the final solution should be looks like exactly in this way:

```css
.stack {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.c1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.c1 img {
  width: 300px;
}

.c2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  background: bluex;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.c3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellowx;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 11px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
  <div class="c1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me, to extend or rebuild this for the other requirements.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  It is generally expected that you at least make an attempt to solve your problem and if you are stuck with a particular peice of code, then ask for help with that

Comment: In response to your questions - responsive - don't use fixed units, use relative units like percent, vw, ems or rems.  React top resize - not sure what you want it to do, making it responsive should make it react.   Adjust it's height - make the image width a percent with height auto

Comment: Thank you, i will try it ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try multiple `box-shadow`

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow:
    6px -6px 0 #fff,
    8px -8px 0 #000,
    12px -12px 0 #fff,
    14px -14px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u need.

```
<div class="stack">
    <div class="c1">

    </div>
    <div class="c2-a"></div>
        <div class="c2-b"></div>
    <div class="c3-a"></div>
</div>


    .stack { 
      margin-top:50px;
      position:relative;
    }
    .c1 { 
      z-index: 10;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width:95%;
      background:red;
      background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:100% auto;
      padding-top:70%; /*adjust the padding value */ 

    } 

    .c2-a { 
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        background:bluex;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
      top:-7px;
      right:3%;
      width:90%;
    }

    .c2-b { 
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        background:bluex;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
      top:-15px;
      right:0;
      width:80%;
    }
    .c3-a { 
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        background:yellowx;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
      right:0;
      top:-15px;
      padding-top:70%;

    }
    .c3-b {
      /* create the onther line lol */
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqjwv48r/4/

Comment: Thanks for your time, i use the image solution.

Answer (score -1):

Different solution with jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width = $(".c1").width();
    $(".c2").css({'width':(width +'px'), 'height':(width +'px')});
    $(".c3").css({'width':(width +'px'), 'height':(width +'px')});
});
```

```css
.stack {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.c1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.c1 img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.c2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  background: bluex;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.c3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellowx;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stack">
  <div class="c1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200.png/09f/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```